# Spark structured streaming job parameters for writing .compact files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm currently streaming from a file source, but every time a .compact file needs to be written, there's a big latency spike (~5 minutes; the .compact files are about 2.7GB). This is kind of aggravating because I'm trying to keep a rolling window's latency below a threshold and throwing an extra five minutes on there once every, say, half-hour messes with that.

Are there any spark parameters for tweaking .compact file writes? This system seems very lightly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran into a reported bug: [SPARK-30462 - Structured Streaming _spark_metadata fills up Spark Driver memory when having lots of objects](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30462) which was fixed in Spark version 3.1.

Before that version there are no other configurations to prevent the compact file to be growing incrementally while using quite a lot of memory which makes the compaction slow.

Here is description of the [Release Note](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/04/27/whats-new-in-apache-spark-3-1-release-for-structured-streaming.html) on Structured Streaming:

> **Streamline the logic on file stream source and sink metadata log (SPARK-30462)**
>
> Before this change, whenever the metadata was needed in FileStreamSource/Sink, all entries in the metadata log were deserialized into the Spark driver’s memory. With this change, Spark will read and process the metadata log in a streamlined fashion whenever possible.

Comment: Ah, interesting - this cluster is running 3.1.1, but only upgraded to it a month or two ago. My guess is the old records are still kicking around in the .compact file.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner do I throw in the towel, than an answer appears. According to the Jacek Laskowski's book on Spark here: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/content/spark-sql-streaming-properties.html

There is a parameter `spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.compactInterval` that controls this interval. If anyone knows of any other parameters that control this behaviour, though, please let me know!

Comment: A follow-up to this: the reason these files are so large is they track every file that has ever been seen and do not get cleaned up when the source gets cleaned up.